# Developer menu not showing on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

**Disclaimer 1**: I know this kind of question has been addressed multiple times, but in my case it seems a little bit different.

**Disclaimer 2**: I can't use an emulator because the app is dealing with bluetooth devices.

[image: Debugging is enabled]

As you can see in the picture above, there is a warning about the react native debugger being in the background. So this should indicate that developer mode is on? And the menu should be available?

I shake my phone and nothing happens, no developer menu.
I just want to enable hot reload and I can't.

It used to work previously but I can't seem to find what's changed in the iOS project.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT 1**: Code from AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"RXApp"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

**EDIT 2**: This working perfectly fine on Android.

**EDIT 3**: This seems to be related to [using Cocoa Pods](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2394).

Comment: Can you share code of AppDelegate.m

Comment: I've shared the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by getting rid of CocoaPods/react-native-link and integrating all my native modules manually. Now the menu is back and all my additional problems vanished.

Comment: I did that awhile ago but the developer menu still doesn't show.

Answer (score 11):

- Select debug mode in  current schema.
- Go to Product > Schema > Edit schema > select Run option and change Build configuration to Debug

**NOTE: Your device and pc should be in same network**

Comment: try to kill all server process using "killall node -9" command and again run "npm start" and i edit my answer

Comment: I did that already and for what it's worth, this is working perfectly fine simultaneously on Android

Comment: Thank you thank you! Make sure you take the schema off of "release" and onto "Debug". Saved me many hours